# Removing duplicates based on value in other column in pandas

Tags: pandas

I am trying to remove the duplicates in column `duplicates` and keep only the records where the value in column `name` is equal to "foo". Is there a better way to do it than my approach?

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {"name": ["foo", "bar", "foo", "baz"], "duplicates": ["qux", "qux", "fred", "fred"]}
)
df["name"] = df["name"].map({"foo": "a"})
df.sort_values(["name", "duplicates"], inplace=True, ascending=True)
df.drop_duplicates("duplicates")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your solution need also values if not match `foo` if not exist per groups by `duplicates`, right?

Then solution is use [`DataFrameGroupBy.idxmax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.idxmax.html) for first `True`s per groups with msk for compare `foo` - if not exist get first `False` value:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {"name": ["foo", "bar", "foo", "baz","bez"], 
     "duplicates": ["qux", "qux", "fred", "fred","John"]}
)
print (df)
  name duplicates
0  foo        qux
1  bar        qux
2  foo       fred
3  baz       fred
4  bez       John

df = df.loc[df["name"].eq('foo').groupby(df['duplicates']).idxmax()]

print (df)
  name duplicates
4  bez       John
2  foo       fred
0  foo        qux
```

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you original df is

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {"name": ["foo", "bar", "foo", "baz"], "duplicates": ["qux", "qux", "fred", "fred"]}
)
```

Output is

|  | name | duplicates |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | foo | qux |
| 1 | bar | qux |
| 2 | foo | fred |
| 3 | baz | fred |

How about this?

```
df[
    df['duplicates']\
        .isin(df.groupby('duplicates')\
                .size()\
                .reset_index(name='count')\
                .query('count>1')['duplicates']
            )
    ].query('name=="foo"')
```

So you will get

|  | name | duplicates |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | foo | qux |
| 2 | foo | fred |